# Moving a View in a loop

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make my view move in a loop around 4 corners. I did it by having a keyList. Originally my view is constrained to top and left border.
[image: picture]

After each click, I update the keylist by removing first index of keyList and move it to the last.

I have this code currently. The view moves fine for the first 4 corners (1 loop) but the app crashed after.

```
    var keyList = arrayListOf(1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0)

    val puckMinX = border.minX().toFloat()
    val puckMaxX = (border.maxX() - puck.width).toFloat()
    val puckMinY= border.minY().toFloat()
    val puckMaxY = (border.maxY() - puck.height).toFloat()

    fun clickTextView(view: ImageView) {
        if (keyList[0] == 0) {
            puck.x = puckMinX
            puck.y = puckMinY
            var holder =keyList[0]
            keyList.remove(holder)
            keyList+holder}
        else if (keyList[0] == 1) {
            puck.x = puckMaxX
            puck.y = puckMinY
            var holder =keyList[0]
            keyList
            keyList.remove(holder)
            keyList+holder}
        else if (keyList[0] == 2) {
            puck.x = puckMaxX
            puck.y = puckMaxY
            var holder =keyList[0]
            keyList.remove(holder)
            keyList+holder}
        else if (keyList[0] == 3) {
            puck.x = puckMinX
            puck.y = puckMaxY
            var holder =keyList[0]
            keyList.remove(holder)
             keyList+holder}
    }

    //applying lambda to each textview
    puck.setOnClickListener { clickTextView(puck) }
```

Could someone tell me what I did wrong? Or also is there a better way to make my view move in a loop? Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I found the problem. My list is only removing the first index but not adding the item that's removed back to the list. How do I update my keylist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [add](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/add.html) which adds element to end of the list

```
keyList.add(holder)
```

Edit

**Note** that you wont be able to print like `println(keyList.add(holder))` because `add` will return `true` since it will successfully update the list. So you will have to do

```
keyList.add(holder)
println(keyList)
```

Comment: I just noticed the println lol. Also keyList.add(holder) works! Thanks! I appreciate it!